# Angular Observable subscription failing if defensive coding / error checking is omitted

Tags: angular, observable

I'm using Angular 8 with SignalR. I'm pushing an observable from my NotificationService to a DashboardComponent. For testing, I'm sending through a test message every 10 seconds.

If I omit some defensive coding in my subscription handler, the subscription fails - even though the actual notification messages come through in the correct format so shouldn't technically need it. Also I get a one-off error message from the subscription handler which appears to be executed (with an empty object {}) as the subscription is registered. Probably best explained by the code:

**Observable:** 
(NotificationListenerService)

```js
 private doorMessageSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  doorMessage$: Observable<any> = this.doorMessageSource.asObservable();
```

**Raiser:**
(NotificationListenerService)

```js
this.doorMessageSource.next(notificationMessage);
```

**Subscribe:**
(DashboardComponent)

```js
constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private _router: Router, private _notificationListener: NotificationListenerService) {
    this.doorSubscription = this._notificationListener.doorMessage$
      .subscribe((notificationMessage) => {
        this.handleDoorMessage(notificationMessage);
      });
  }
```

**Handler: (SUBSCRIPTION FAILS - NO SUBSEQUENT EVENTS HANDLED)**
(DashboardComponent)

```js
  doorSubscription: Subscription;
  private handleDoorMessage(notificationMessage): void {
    // Note - This line does not fail even when notificationMessage = {}
    var message = notificationMessage.PayloadMessage;
    var messageId = notificationMessage.MessageId;

    // This line throws a one-off error message on subscription because 
    // notificationMessage = {} so message = undefined
    console.log(message.Timestamp + ' handleDoorMessage: ' + message.Name);

  }
```

**Handler: (WORKING)**
(DashboardComponent)

```js
  doorSubscription: Subscription;
  private handleDoorMessage(notificationMessage): void {
    var message = notificationMessage.PayloadMessage;
    var messageId = notificationMessage.MessageId;
    if (message) {
      // Executes correctly for my test messages every 10 seconds
      console.log(message.Timestamp + ' handleDoorMessage: ' + message.Name);
    } else {
      // Executes once 
      console.log('handleDoorMessage ERROR: Message Format Invalid');
    }
  }
```

So, I'm really just wondering what's going on here? Why is my subscription handler being invoked with an empty object on registration? Is it a bug? Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Post your doorMessage observable please

Comment: No worries. Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the nature of `BehaviorSubject`. `BehaviorSubject` emits the last emitted value as SOON as a subscriber subscribes to the `BehaviorSubject`. When `BehaviorSubject` is instantiated, it is must to specify the initial value. In your case, it is an empty object (i.e. `{}`).

Because of this reason, you see that a one time message is logged.

If you do not want this behavior, you can use `Subject` which does not remember [also it does not want to have initial value at the time of instantiation] the last emitted value. Having said that, the subscriber will receive only those values which are emitted AFTER the subscription to the `Subject` instance.

Also once, an exception has occurred in the observable pipeline, the observable will be in error state and it cannot emit new values. See the following link: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. Particularly the error-handling bit which clearly puts extra emphasis on defensive coding within any Observable handlers